# IE7 Spacing issue in floating DIVs with margin left and right

Tags: html, css

I wanna create some columns with width and margins in percentage in DIVs can fit, inside any container with dynamic width.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/uAzg2/)

```
<div class="gridFluid">
    <div class="col-1-4"></div>
    <div class="col-1-4"></div>
    <div class="col-1-4"></div>
    <div class="col-1-4"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
 * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
 body {
     font-size: 1%
 }
 .gridFluid {
     width: 960px;
     display: table;
     background: #eee;
     font-size: 0px;
     overflow: auto;
     zoom: 1;
 }
 .col-1-4 {
     background: #ddd;
     height: 200px;
     width: 23%;
     display: table-cell;
     *display: inline;
     zoom:1;
     margin-left: 1%;
     margin-right: 1%;
     float: left;
 }
```

It's working as expected everywhere, but in IE7 last column is not able to fit properly in single line. May be because it's adding extra space between DIVs other then margin.

I don't want to use different width or margin for IE7 (width: 24.5% instead 25). Because it's not a proper solution. I'm looking for a good solution for it.

May be it's Known issue of IE7, I find lot of issue related to it when i'm searching for solution but not get any proper way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do some quick calculations based off of your CSS.

You want each column to be 23% of the width of the container. So each column should be:

> .23 * 960 = 220.8

So each column should be 220.8 pixels.

You want the margins to each be 1% wide.

> .01 * 960 = 9.6

So each margin should be 9.6 pixels wide.

Wait a minute. We've got some partial pixels in there. How do you handle a .8 or a .6 of a pixel? Well you have to do some rounding. But which way do you round... up or down? Well if you round up you end up with 4 columns sized 221 pixels.

> 221 * 4 = 884

So the total width of the columns is an estimated 884 pixels.

What about the margins?

> 8 * 10 = 80

So the total width of the margins is an estimated 80 pixels.

Now let's add those numbers together.

> 80 + 884 = 964

Hrmm... looks like we've got 4 extra pixels here... better push the content down a line to fit in the 960px wide box.

That's why your columns are being pushed down.
Also, check out: http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Comment: Thanks, to explain it in details. Now i got what the problem is. Do you have any solution for it? For example same thing is working correctly if we've margins is define in single side. For example if we define margin-right: 2% or margin-left 2% is same case it'll work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Just make a small change to your css...

**Change:-**

```
.col-1-4 {
     width: 23%;     
 }
```

**To this:-**

```
.col-1-4 {
     *width: 22.9%; 
     width: 23%;    
 }
```

Comment: As i mention in my question i'm trying to ignore it. Because it'll just give you a approx result, not exact same width as my parent

Comment: their is no other solution for this since it is an IE bug so you have to use the css hack...

Answer (score 0):

How about double divs's. That will obviously solve the problem.

```
 .col-1-4 {
     position:relative;
     background: #eee;
     height: 200px;
     width: 25%;
    /*******************************/
    /* Don't use this properties, not necessary here */
     display: table-cell;
     *display: inline;
    /*******************************/
     zoom:1;
     float: left;
 }
 .col-1-4>div {
     background: #ddd;
     position:absolute;
     left:4%;
     right:4%;  /* 100/25 = 4 */
     top:0;
     bottom:0;
 }
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uAzg2/1/)

Comment: Yes that what i thought too, But problem is extra div in every place is not make sence

Comment: @Tarun I hope you have only 4 div's as you mentioned here?

Comment: it's only example, i could have more div's

Comment: @Tarun Just a suggestion, if there is no content inside those child divs, then you can just copy paste as other child div's. Anyway, I hope you will get the answer soon. good luck :)